# Copy files in different subdirectories that excludes a string

Tags: find, wildcards, cp

I'm trying to copy all files of a type in a given directory and subdirectories but excluding files of a different type.

`find /var/ftp/pub/bs -iname "*foo*.foo" -exec cp {} /var/ftp/pub/bs1 \;`

which works but I'd rather do the exclude which is more accurate.

So I need to copy files with that end with `*.foo` but exclude files that contain `foo1`

Something like this (which doesn't work)

```
find /var/ftp/pub/bs -iname "*.foo" | grep --exclude="*foo1*" -exec cp {} /var/ftp/pub/bs1
```

Answer (score 4):

```
find ... -iname "*.foo" ! -iname "*foo1*" ...
```

You may need to escape the `!` depending on your shell.

Comment: That worked.  I did need to escape it.  Thanks much!